Validation of Latch LS374 data
I'm using LS374 Latch, and I have two of them. I have captured the data that goes into the latch, and that outputs from the latch, at clock signal. I recorded the data from logic analyzer that goes to and out to the latches into a text file. I wrote a small C++ program that checks if the latch is working probably or not.
here is my sample processing code, IOWR is clock signal to LS374
The problem is I get some time slices that latch are incorrect, as shown in the figure
is my approach correct of validating the data ?

MVP:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Data {
    double time;
    int latchA1, latchCS1, latchCS2;
    int D0, D1, D2, D3;
    int IOWR;
    int MPC_A1, MPC_CS1, MPC_CS2;
    int MPC_D0, MPC_D1, MPC_D2, MPC_D3;
};

// Function to load data from a text file
vector<Data> loadData(const string& filename) {
    vector<Data> dataList;
    ifstream file(filename);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
        return dataList;
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        Data data;
        char comma;
        ss >> data.time >> comma
            >> data.latchA1 >> comma
            >> data.latchCS1 >> comma
            >> data.latchCS2 >> comma
            >> data.D0 >> comma
            >> data.D1 >> comma
            >> data.D2 >> comma
            >> data.D3 >> comma
            >> data.IOWR >> comma
            >> data.MPC_A1 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_CS1 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_CS2 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_D0 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_D1 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_D2 >> comma
            >> data.MPC_D3;
        dataList.push_back(data);
    }

    file.close();
    return dataList;
}

// Function to combine Qs (Latch Outputs) into a single hex value
string combineQsToHex(const Data& data) {
    // Combine Latch outputs into an 8-bit value
    int latchOutput = (data.latchA1 << 6) | (data.latchCS1 << 5) | (data.latchCS2 << 4) | (data.D0 << 3) | (data.D1 << 2) | (data.D2 << 1) | data.D3;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << latchOutput;
    return ss.str();
}

// Function to combine Ds (MPC Inputs) into a single hex value
string combineDsToHex(const Data& data) {
    // Combine MPC inputs into an 8-bit value
    int mpcInput = (data.MPC_A1 << 6) | (data.MPC_CS1 << 5) | (data.MPC_CS2 << 4) | (data.MPC_D0 << 3) | (data.MPC_D1 << 2) | (data.MPC_D2 << 1) | data.MPC_D3;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << mpcInput;
    return ss.str();
}

// Function to print hex data
void printHexData(const Data& data) {
    cout << "Time: " << fixed << setprecision(10) << data.time << "s\t";
    cout << "Latch Output (Hex): 0x" << combineQsToHex(data) << "\t";
    cout << "MPC Input (Hex): 0x" << combineDsToHex(data) << endl;
}

// Function to process latch data
void processLatchData(const vector<Data>& dataList) {
    bool lastIOWRWas1 = false;
    bool transitionDetected = false;

    for (const auto& data : dataList) {
        if (data.IOWR == 0 && lastIOWRWas1 && !transitionDetected) {
            // Detected transition from 1 to 0
            transitionDetected = true;
        }
        else if (data.IOWR == 1 && transitionDetected) {
            // Detected transition from 0 to 1
            string latchHex = combineQsToHex(data);
            string mpcHex = combineDsToHex(data);
            if (latchHex == mpcHex) {
                printHexData(data);
            }
            else {
                cout << "Incorrect latch at time: " << fixed << setprecision(10) << data.time << "s" << endl;
                printHexData(data);
            }
            transitionDetected = false; // Reset the transition detection flag
        }
        lastIOWRWas1 = (data.IOWR == 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    string filename = "data.txt";  // Specify your filename here
    vector<Data> dataList = loadData(filename);

    if (dataList.empty()) {
        cerr << "No data to process." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    processLatchData(dataList);

    return 0;
}

Sample Data file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/7uwi4ur1d6iosn5/30.07.2024+without+internal+lcd2.rar/file

Don't use off-site links, don't use links that do not work in any case, don't post pictures of text. No embedded code here. Why the tag?  Since it is a question about a non-programmable electronic device, better asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

According to the datasheet Qn is valid and stable when both /OC and CLK are low.  It is not clear what signal you are using for /OC, but you are reading the Q data when CLK is high which is clearly incorrect.

You need to acquire the D data on CLK 0->1 and the Q data On CLK 1->0
By capturing Q on the rising clock, you are in a device propagation race condition dependent on the asynchronous sampling of the logic analyser.  The propagation time D to Q on a clock edge is 15 to 28 nanoseconds, so reading Q on the clock edge is not going to work reliably.

The rising arrow notation indicates that that line of the truth table becomes applicable when the changed signal changes as indicated, and will remain applicable until some other line applies.  Note that depending upon the state of D on the rising edge of Clk, either the first or second line of the truth table may be applicable.  The table is incomplete, though, as it fails to describe the fact that a rising edge on CLK when /OC is high will capture the state of D into Q0, and output that state of /OC goes low before the next rising edge of Clk.

@supercat I am not sure who your comment is aimed at and whether you are adding information or disputing the answer.  The point is that the code is not operating or reading the latch, it is processing sampled logic-analyser data.  While it is true that Q moves to the D state on rising CLK, it takes time, and the logic analyser sample may or may not have occurred after that time.  Besides the behaviour of either the latch or the logic analyser are off topic, the correctness of the code analysing the capture is the on-topic issue.

@supercat your last point about rising CLK high when /OC goes low is correct, but academic - that would be a design error in normal use as an addressable latch.  When using MCU bus signals, it would be difficult to do that.

@Clifford not just academic ... its crucial for what Ahmed is aiming to do (reading the LATCH by STM32 and decode captured stuff into image) which means a small delay inside rising edge of /CLK  ISR is needed ... however he still faces electrical problems as captured data shows LATCHES work only for some time and then not at all ... the problem is he is low in EE knowledge and this is 16-32 MHz signal which brings up a lot of VHF problems (which I am not familiar enough with to help more then just guesses and trial and errors)

@Spektre no he is not doing that, he is processing logic analyser capture. That would be relevant if he were questioning the hardware design.  The analysis code is the subject of the question, and  that does not read the Q data on the correct transition.  I have no idea how you have determined that STM32 is involved here.  ihe IOWR signal suggests other since STM32 does not have an IO bus separate from memory bus.  The timing information is given elsewhere in the datasheet, but is not relevant to the question.

@Clifford this is just a minor follow up problem of his task many relevant info is in the consequent questions and chats of OP you probably didn't see yet ... as OP did not post the links in here

@Spektre I can only address the question as asked here and only in so far as it is on-topic here.  No doubt there are issues related to why he captured this data in the first place, but our task here is simply to correct the processing of that data, not to fix his hardware.

@Spektre Moreover your point about a delay after /CLK is not the same point supercat made about /CLK preceding /OC.  I already made the point about propagation delay and Q being valid (latched) only on the falling edge of /CLK.

@Clifford that might sound safe but brings up problem later (which was already encountered) that the final app (LCD emulator) is one frame behind ... making menus sometimes stuck in wrong frame (once regular LCD update stops)... as you does not read the last word of the LCD frame until new frame is present. That i swhy the read is done on rising edge of /IOWR

@Spektre you seem determined to miss the point.  That issue is not in scope.  If the OP has other issues then they need to ask a different question on an appropriate site.  I appreciate you are trying to assist, but in that case you're comments are more appropriately posted against the question, not this answer, which addresses exactly the question asked.  If after interpreting the logic analyser data correctly, the there remains a data mismatch, then that is an actual problem with the system being analysed, and not a problem with this analysis code.
